# Drop a MySQL event if a condition is met

Tags: mysql

I've a table (table_rne) like

```
id     maxv     curv
1      200        20
```

And I've created an event (increase_curv) which will increase 'curv' by 10 every 1 minute

```
CREATE EVENT increase_curv
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 8 SECOND
DO
UPDATE table_rne SET curv = curv + 10 WHERE id='1';
```

But I want to drop the event when 'curv' reaches maxv (200). How to do that using MySQL conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this;

```
CREATE EVENT increase_curv
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 8 SECOND
DO   
IF curv < 200 THEN
  UPDATE table_rne SET curv = curv + 10 WHERE id='1' 
ELSE
  DROP EVENT [IF EXISTS] increase_curv
END IF;
```